# Create a new excel column with the number of repetitions a value occurs in each row of a column with PANDAS

Tags: python, pandas

I have an excel file with the column A (names) and column B (description) in which i have a long description of the profile of the person.
It looks like:

```
Name             Description
James R          A good systems developer...
```

I'm trying to count how many times for example the word 'good' appears in each row of the column 'description' and create a new column with the number of repetitions. I have a lot of values so I prefer to use pandas than excel formulas. 
The output should look like this:

```
Name             Description                   Good
James R          A good systems developer...     1
```

The python code that I develop is this:

```
In [1]: import collections

In [2]: import pandas as pd

In [3]: df=pd.read_excel('israel2013.xls')

In [4]: str1=df.description

In [5]: str2= 'good'

In [6]: for index, row in df.iterrows():
   ...:     if str2 in str1:
   ...:         counter=collections.Counter (r[0] for str2 in str1)
   ...:     else:
   ...:         print (0)
```

But I get all zeros from this, and I don't know whats wrong.
Thank you

Comment: Please include a [MCVE]. Vague descriptions of your input data and how the output data should look like are not helpful. Also, you seem to have figured out how to load and write excel files with pandas, so why does the question even mention excel?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Demo dataframe:

```
>>> data = [['James R', 'A good systems developer'], ['Bob C', 'a guy called Bob'], ['Alice R', 'Good teacher and a good runner']]                                           
>>> df = pd.DataFrame(data, columns=['Name', 'Description'])                                                                                                                 
>>>                                                                                                                                                                          
>>> df                                                                                                                                                                       
      Name                     Description
0  James R        A good systems developer
1    Bob C                a guy called Bob
2  Alice R  Good teacher and a good runner
```

Solution:

```
>>> df['Good'] = df.Description.str.count(r'(?i)\bgood\b')                                                                                                       
>>> df                                                                                                                                                                       
      Name                     Description  Good
0  James R        A good systems developer     1
1    Bob C                a guy called Bob     0
2  Alice R  Good teacher and a good runner     2
```

`\b` marks word boundaries, `(?i)` performs a case-insensitive search. Alternatively to using `(?i)`, you could `import re` and supply `flags=re.IGNORECASE` as the second argument to `count`.

Answer (score 0):

Try:

```
df['Good'] = df['description'].str.findall('good').str.len()
```